# How can I get only the most recent date in my Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

I am a very new SQL User (I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012) and have just started using `CASE`.  My end goal is to have 1 `ScoreDecile` for each customer. In the example below I have been able create the `CASE` Statement that will identify the `ScoreDecile` but because my data files are monthly (and time frame is 1 year) I am obviously getting 12 different scores for each customer.  How can I get the `ScoreDecile` from only the most current month? Thank you VERY much for your help!

```
SELECT 
    A.household_id
    ,SUM (a.contacted) AS Contacted
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0740734327 AND a.[Score] < 1) THEN '1'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.051522993 AND a.[Score] < 0.0740722882) THEN '2'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0410156448 AND a.[Score] < 0.051522951) THEN '3'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0344048467 AND a.[Score] < 0.0410156323) THEN '4'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.029530965 AND a.[Score] < 0.0344046968) THEN '5'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0254069538 AND a.[Score] < 0.0295309522) THEN '6'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.021865371 AND a.[Score] < 0.0254069523) THEN '7'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0185329571 AND a.[Score] < 0.0218653642) THEN  '8'
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0151799201 AND a.[Score] < 0.0185329032) THEN '9'  
        WHEN (a.[Score] > 0.0011824404 AND a.[Score] < 0.0151796708) THEN '10'
    END AS 'ScoreDecile'
INTO
    #temp2
FROM
    [TABLE_A] A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #TEMP B ON A.customerid = b.customerid
WHERE 
    A.[date] BETWEEN '2014-04-14' AND '2015-03-15'
GROUP BY 
    a.household_id, a.score
HAVING 
    SUM (a.contacted) = 0
ORDER BY 
    household_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data for the current calendar month, I guess, you need to replace

```
A.[date] BETWEEN '2014-04-14' AND '2015-03-15'
```

with

```
A.[date] > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```